# How do I extract the principal component`s values of all observations using psych package

Tags: r, dimensionality-reduction, psych

I'm performing dimensionality reduction using the `psych` package. After analyzing the scree plot I decided to use the 9 most important PCs (out of 15 variables) to build a linear model.
My question is, how do I extract the values of the 9 most important PCs for each of the 500 observations I have? Is there any built in function for that, or do I have to manually compute it using the loadings matrix?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Returns eigen values, loadings, and degree of fit for a specified number of components after performing an eigen value decomposition. Essentially, it involves doing a principal components analysis (PCA) on n principal components of a correlation or covariance matrix. Can also display residual correlations.By comparing residual correlations to original correlations, the quality of the reduction in squared correlations is reported. In contrast to princomp, this only returns a subset of the best nfactors. To obtain component loadings more characteristic of factor analysis, the eigen vectors are rescaled by the sqrt of the eigen values.

```r
principal(r, nfactors = 1, residuals = FALSE,rotate="varimax",n.obs=NA, covar=FALSE,
          scores=TRUE,missing=FALSE,impute="median",oblique.scores=TRUE,
          method="regression",...)
```

I think So.